# StackExchange.Redis: Does a transaction hit the server multiple times?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

When I execute a transaction (MULTI/EXEC) via SE.Redis, does it hit the server multiple times? For example,

```
        ITransaction tran = Database.CreateTransaction();
        tran.AddCondition(Condition.HashExists(cacheKey, oldKey));

        HashEntry hashEntry = GetHashEntry(newKeyValuePair);

        Task fieldDeleteTask = tran.HashDeleteAsync(cacheKey, oldKey);
        Task hashSetTask = tran.HashSetAsync(cacheKey, new[] { hashEntry });

        if (await tran.ExecuteAsync())
        {
            await fieldDeleteTask;
            await hashSetTask;
        }
```

Here I am executing two tasks in the transaction. Does this mean I hit the server 4 times? 1 for MULTI, 1 for delete, 1 for set, 1 for exec? Or is SE.Redis smart enough to buffer the tasks in local memory and send everything in one shot when we call `ExecuteAsync`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has to send multiple *commands*, but it doesn't pay latency costs per command; specifically, when you call `Execute[Async]` (and not before) it issues a pipeline (all together, not waiting for replies) of:

```
WATCH cacheKey                  // observes any competing changes to cacheKey
HEXIST cacheKey oldKey          // see if the existing field exists
MULTI                           // starts the transacted commands
HDEL cacheKey oldKey            // delete the existing field
HSET cachKey newField newValue  // assign the new field
```

*then* it pays latency costs to get the result from the `HEXIST`, because only when that is known can it decide whether to proceed with the transaction (issuing `EXEC` and checking the result - which can be negative if the `WATCH` detects a conflict), or whether to throw everything away (`DISCARD`).

So; either way 6 commands are going to be issued, but in terms of latency: you're paying for 2 round trips due to the need for a decision point before the final `EXEC`/`DISCARD`. In many cases, though, this can itself be further masked by the reality that the result of `HEXIST` could already be on the way back to you before we've even got as far as checking, especially if you have any non-trivial bandwidth, for example a large `newValue`.

---

However! As a general rule: anything you *can* do with redis `MULTI`/`EXEC`: can be done *faster, more reliably, and with fewer bugs*, by using a Lua script instead. It looks like what we're actually trying to do here is:

> for the hash `cacheKey`, if (and only if) the field `oldField` exists: remove `oldField` and set `newField` to `newValue`

We can do this *very simply* in Lua, because Lua scripts are executed at the server from start to finish without interruption from competing connections. This means that we don't need to worry about things like atomicity i.e. other connections changing data that we're making decisions with. So:

```cs
var success = (bool)await db.ScriptEvaluateAsync(@"
if redis.call('hdel', KEYS[1], ARGV[1]) == 1 then
    redis.call('hset', KEYS[1], ARGV[2], ARGV[3])
    return true
else
    return false
end
", new RedisKey[] { cacheKey }, new RedisValue[] { oldField, newField, newValue });
```

The verbatim string literal here is our Lua script, noting that we don't need to do a separate `HEXISTS`/`HDEL` any more - we can make our decision based on the result of the `HDEL`. Behind the scenes, the library performs `SCRIPT LOAD` operations as needed, so: if you are doing this lots of times, it doesn't need to send the script itself over the network more than once.

From the perspective of the client: you are now only paying a single latency fee, *and* we're not sending the same things repeatedly (the original code sent `cacheKey` four times, and `oldKey` twice).

---

(a note on the choice of `KEYS` vs `ARGV`: the distinction between *keys* and *values* is important for routing purposes, in particular on sharded environments such as redis-cluster; sharding is done based on the *key*, and the only *key* here is `cacheKey`; the field identifiers in hashes *do not impact sharding*, so for the purpose of routing they are *values*, not *keys* - and as such, you should convey them via `ARGV`, not `KEYS`; this won't impact you on `redis-server`, but on `redis-cluster` this difference is very important, as if you get it wrong: the server will most-likely reject your script, thinking that you are attempting a cross-slot operation; multi-key commands on `redis-cluster` are only supported when all the keys are on the same *slot*, usually achieved via "hash tags")

Comment: thanks a lot. I have a small confusion. You say `you're paying for 2 round trips due to the need for a decision point before the final EXEC/DISCARD` and also later say `and we're not sending the same things repeatedly (the original code sent cacheKey four times, and oldKey twice).` I dont get the second sentence. In my original code, when execution is complete, aren't we incurring a penalty of sending them twice, one for `HEXIST` and one for `EXEC/DISCARD` ?

Comment: Btw, it would have been cool if just call `ExecuteAsync` and you convert the whole thing into LUA and run a `ScriptEvaluateAsync` behind the scenes :P

Comment: @nawfal and quite possibly entirely doable, but: it is a non-trivial amount of work, too :)

Comment: @nawfal we don't send any *data* in the `EXEC`/`DISCARD` - I'm literally just talking about the keys and values here

Comment: Marc, Ok got it.